# Loop throught form inputs

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, loops

I have a form with lots of inputs. I want to get each id and value and then put them in $.load method. I tried this:

```
$("#form input").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("id");
    var value = $(this).attr("value");
    $.extend(params, {
        name, value
    });
});
```

and then use `$.load("script.php", params);`

But obviously it doesn't work. In params I have only one element "name". And I'm not sure I should use extend method too.

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to `.serialize()` the `$('#form')` and AJAX that?

Comment: Form elements are picked up based on their `name`, not `id` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serialize the form you can use the [jQuery serialize method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) like so:

```
var params = $("#form").serialize();
$.load("script.php", params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you want to build is an array of objects with two properties (name/value), here is the code to get it:

```
var myparams = [];
$("form input").each(function() {

    // build an object literal to store your values
    var o = {
        name: this.id, // no need to turn 'this' in a jquery object to get the ID
        value: $(this).val()  // use .val() to get the value
    };

    myparams.push(o); // add to the array
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
var params={};

$('input').each(function(){
    params[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(params);
```

output

```
bar: "bar"
bof: "bof"
foo: "foo"
```

See it here on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnH7b/)